# How to upgrade Python Pandas version?

Tags: python, pandas, upgrade

I am using Python in Jupyter Notebook. My Pandas version is

```
pandas: 0.23.4
```

in which I cannot use Explode or other advanced functions. I am trying to upgrade it using the codes like:

```
!pip install -- upgrade pandas
```

But keep receiving error messages like:

> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/ipython/: There was a
> problem confirming the ssl certificate:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /simple/ipython/ (Caused by
> SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
> (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping

Does anyone know how to rewrite the codes?

Comment: Can't you just write `!pip install --upgrade pandas` to only upgrade pandas?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote !pip install -- upgrade pandas, and got that error message.

Comment: Is your computer behind a _firewall_ or something? This can be the case in work computers, and this message looks similar to those cases

Comment: A solution might be to write `pip install --upgrade pandas --trusted-host https://pypi.org/simple/ipython/`, see eg. [here](https://ao.ms/pip-there-was-a-problem-confirming-the-ssl-certificate/)

Comment: I tried and it also got an error: The following command must be run outside of the IPython shell:

    $ pip install --upgrade pandas --trusted-host https://pypi.org/simple/ipython/

The Python package manager (pip) can only be used from outside of IPython.
Please reissue the `pip` command in a separate terminal or command prompt.

Comment: try `!{sys.executable} -m pip install ...`

Comment: Still failed: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping
Directory '...' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.

Comment: This isn't going to help you with the connection/certificate issue; it's more a quality of life improvement in standard Jupyter. In your post you tried `!pip install ...`. In the last couple of years a magic command was added that you should use when using `pip` in a notebook. `%pip install ...` will handle dealing with the environment backing your notebook, whereas the use of the exclamation point won't. A similar magic command was added for `conda`. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information.

Comment: @Sandy we do realize that `!pip install -- upgrade pandas` isn't the same as `!pip install --upgrade pandas` right? In the first one you're trying to install `upgrade` and `pandas`, in the second you're upgrading `pandas`...

Comment: @BeRT2me Yes. Because none of them works, so I just tried all of them...

Answer (score 1):

It might provide a temporary solution. I think there is a proxy or firewall rule restricting connection to pypi.org;

```
pip config set global.trusted-host "pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.python.org" --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to provide more information about your setup, e.g., what operating system do you use. The call `!pip install --upgrade pandas` executes shell command. If, for instance, you use Ubuntu, then this command will try to install the pandas package using system package manager, and it will fail because you need sudo privileges.

It seems that you try to execute locally the code developed for the cloud collaborative platforms (e.g., Google Colab). Unfortunately, you need to do this carefully.

I would recommend to you to create a separate virtual environment for your project and install dependencies there. For instance, I use poetry to manage the dependencies in my projects but you can also use others (virtualenv, anaconda, pipenv, etc.).

Comment: Hi Yury, I am using Windows. I am not using Colab, this is just a Jupyter notebook in my local machine.

Comment: I think my comment below the OP about avoiding the exclamation point with `pip` and `conda` inside a Jupyter notebook cell complements the first paragraph of this answer.

Comment: Thanks @Wayne ! I did not know that a magic has been added to install packages. Still, I would recommend to use some Python package managers to install packages for a project.

Comment: Yes, using environments is still best for managing projects; however, the magic commands insuring things install to the environment backing your current notebook can sometimes more easily help you get past hurdles or test something quickly.